# How do I pass the dictionary values from Controller to View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

I am creating a periodic table and I have created a dictionary in the Home Controller called dictionaryOfElements which has element's atomic number as key and element's atomic number, symbol, name, and weight as values. I need help in displaying all the values of a dictionary to a View from ViewModel.

Below is the Model I created:

```
public class Elements
{
    public int AtomicNumber { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Weight { get; set; }

    public Elements()
    {
        //
    }

    public Elements(int atomic, string sym, string name, string weight)
    {
        this.AtomicNumber = atomic;
        this.Symbol = sym;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Weight = weight;
    }
}
```

Home Controller where I declared the dictionary

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    Elements Hydrogen = new Elements(1, "H", "Hydrogen", "1.008");
    Elements Helium = new Elements(2, "He", "Helium", "4.0026");
    Elements Lithium = new Elements(3, "Li", "Lithium", "6.94");
    Elements Beryllium = new Elements(4, "Be", "Beryllium", "9.0122");
    Dictionary<int, Elements> dictionaryOfElements = new Dictionary<int, Elements>();

    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult DisplayElements()
    {          
        dictionaryOfElements.Add(Hydrogen.AtomicNumber, Hydrogen);
        dictionaryOfElements.Add(Helium.AtomicNumber, Helium);
        dictionaryOfElements.Add(Lithium.AtomicNumber, Lithium);
        dictionaryOfElements.Add(Beryllium.AtomicNumber, Beryllium);

        return View(dictionaryOfElements);
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

View Model for Views

```
public class ElementsOfPeriodicTable
{
    public Elements elements { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, Elements> dictionaryOfElements { get; set; }
}
```

So far this is how my View looks like

```
    @model PeriodicTable.View_Model.ElementsOfPeriodicTable
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DisplayElements";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPage1.cshtml";
}

<h2>DisplayElements</h2>

@{ 
    foreach (var item in Model.dictionaryOfElements)
    {
        <p>
            Atomic Number:
            Symbol:
            Name:
            Weight:
        </p>

    }
}


I want to be able to loop through the dictionary and print all the elements.

    <p>
                Atomic Number:@item.AtomicNumber
                Symbol: @item.Symbol
                Name: @item.Name
                Weight: @item.Weight
    </p>
```

Following loop isn't working for me.

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, Elements> elementKeyValuePair in ictionaryOfElements)
        {

        }
```

Also, how do I display all the values if I just want to search by the dictionary key? For example, I want to be able to do the following:

```
Elements element = dictionaryOfElements[4];
```

Lastly, I will be adding all the 118 elements of the periodic table. Is this the best approach?

Comment: use foreach to loop through, `foreach(KeyValuePair<int, Elements> pair in dictionaryOfElements){  @pair.Value.AtomicNumber; @pair.Value.sym;  }` and use `dicitonaryOfElements.TryGetValue()` to get values by key,  (or) `dictionaryOfElements.ElementAt()` will return you a pair at the index... for this case you're better off using `ArrayList` than `dicitonary`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Elements> item in dictionaryOfElements)` will iterate through each `KeyValuePair` in your dictionary , therefore in your HTML you can do the following:

```
    @foreach(KeyValuePair<int, Elements> item in dictionaryOfElements)
    {
         <p>
            Atomic Number:item.AtomicNumber
            Symbol: item.Symbol
            Name: item.Name
            Weight: item.Weight
         </p>
    }
```

In order to retrieve a specific item, based on a key you can use TryGetValue which will attempt to retrieve a value based on a key. The method will return true or false based on whether the key exists or not. There are no exception to handle unless your key is null.

With that said in your HTML you could do the following:

```
    @{
        Elements item = new Elements();
        if (dictionaryOfElements.TryGetValue(4, out item))
        {
            <p>
                item.AtomicNumber
                item.Symbol
                item.Name
                item.Weight
            </p>
        }
    };
```

*Note* you might need to specify @using Elements at the beginning of your HTML.

Lastly to answer you question , yes it seems a good approach. The only suggestion I would make is to create a ViewModel class ElementViewModel with the same structure as your Model Elements.

The ViewModel will be used to pass data from your controller to your view. In a nutshell a Model define your data structure, if you will - it reflects your database , or how your data is represented.

On the other hand the viewModel is the data structure that you will pass to your View.

In your example - perhaps - there is no advantage in doing so, but I feel that learning the correct structure would help you in Learning C Sharp.

Comment: I am having trouble referencing the Elements and dictionaryOfElements in foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Elements> item in dictionaryOfElements). In my question above I have included the ViewModel I created and I am referencing that in the View - @model PeriodicTable.View_Model.ElementsOfPeriodicTable.

Comment: Have you referenced the objects with @using in your HTML?

Comment: Yes. This is what I ended up writing - `@using PeriodicTable.Models
@model PeriodicTable.View_Model.ElementsOfPeriodicTable`. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

First you should return ElementsOfPeriodicTable object from controller:

```
 public ActionResult DisplayElements()
{          
    dictionaryOfElements.Add(Hydrogen.AtomicNumber, Hydrogen);
    dictionaryOfElements.Add(Helium.AtomicNumber, Helium);
    dictionaryOfElements.Add(Lithium.AtomicNumber, Lithium);
    dictionaryOfElements.Add(Beryllium.AtomicNumber, Beryllium);

    return View(new ElementsOfPeriodicTable{
                                          dictionaryOfElements=dictionaryOfElements
                                           }
             );
}
```

If you do this I think the foreach loop would work:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, Elements> elementKeyValuePair in ictionaryOfElements)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Thank you! ElementsOfPeriodicTable View Model now have only one dictionary property - public Dictionary<int, Elements> elementDictionary { get; set; }. Thanks for helping with the return view statement. It now reads like this - return View(new ElementsOfPeriodicTable { elementDictionary = dictionaryOfElements});